# submit button leads to 404 not found

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to using Angular JS and webstorm, so pardon me if I made a stupid mistake. However, I do not think this is the case in this scenario, because I haven't seen any other posts on stackoverflow with a similar problem. I've built a simple form with webstorm that verifies the user's username and password. If the username and password is correct, then they will be redirected to the dashboard page. Whenever I press the submit button, even when I have already commented out the $location.path() function, I get redirected to a 404 not found page. How can I fix this?

### Login Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
 <body>
<div ng-controller="formValidation">
<form action="/" id="myLogin">
<p>Username<input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username"></p>
<p>Password<input type="text" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password"></p>

<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Log In</button>
</form>

<p>{{username == "admin"}}</p>
<br>
<p>{{password == "root"}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Index Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="App.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

### AngularJS Script

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
   .when('/',{
       templateUrl: 'Login.html'
   })
   .when('/dashboard',{
       templateUrl: 'Dashboard.html'
   })
   .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/'
   });
});

app.controller("formValidation", function ($scope, $location) {
$scope.submit = function () {
    var uName = $scope.username;
    var password = $scope.password;

    if (uName =="admin" && password == "root"){
       // $location.path('/dashboard');
    }else {
        //alert("Wrong Password or Username");
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the `action` attribute in the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) tells the browser to submit the form to the specified URL. In Angular you can use the [`ngSubmit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive instead. And as specified in the docs you don't need to specify `ngClick` on the submit button if `ngSubmit` is used.

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" id="myLogin">
  <p>Username
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username">
  </p>
  <p>Password
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password">
  </p>

  <button type="submit">Log In</button>
```

**UPDATE**: I just realized you have two full HTML pages in your example. Angular apps with using the [router](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) are designed to work as a SPA (Singe Page Application). So they `Login.html` needs to be made into a view template like the following:

```
<div ng-controller="formValidation">
  <form id="myLogin" ng-submit="submit()">
    <p>Username
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username">
    </p>
    <p>Password
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password">
    </p>

    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>

  <p>{{username == "admin"}}</p>
  <br>
  <p>{{password == "root"}}</p>
</div>
```

But then you will also need to be able to load that template into `Index.html` for it to be accessible by Angular. You can do this by using a [`script` template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="App.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/Login.html">
    <div>
      <form id="myLogin" ng-submit="submit()">
        <p>Username
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username">
        </p>
        <p>Password
          <input type="text" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password">
        </p>

        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>

      <p>{{username == "admin"}}</p>
      <br>
      <p>{{password == "root"}}</p>
    </div>
  </script>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

And finally you can assign the controller for that view in your router config:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'Login.html'
      controller: 'formValidation'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
      templateUrl: 'Dashboard.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

I'd recommend going through a few more Angular router tutorials to help build your understanding of Angular and SPAs.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but that doesn't seem to be the source of the error. After I click the submit button, I still get redirected to a 404 not found page. However, when I click back, I am redirected to the page I was supposed to go to. It seems like the submit button did redirect me to the correct page, but immediately after I was again redirected to another page. @JasonCust

Comment: @AaronGe I realized some bigger problems with your posted code. Hopefully this clears it up a bit for you.